# How to adjust backlight on a laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hp-pavilion, brightness, backlight

I have an HP laptop and I am not satisfied on the brightness of the screen. The screen brightness setting is already at maximum. Is there a way how to adjust backlight of a laptop.

Comment: Not if you've set it to 100%. A few possible ways forward though. 1) Replace the backlight for a new one, yours may be worn out. 2) Plug in an external monitor which has a brighter screen. 3) Change where the laptop is located, so you're not too close to bright light sources. 4) Try a diffuser/anti-glare filter.

Answer (score 0):

1.Adjust brightness via Color Management:
Search for `Color Managemen`t from search box >click on Advanced Tab>go through `Calibrate Display wizard.`

2.Update the BIOS and graphics driver:
In Windows, open HP Support Assistant.
Select your laptop, and then check for and install any updates.

Comment: Do you have a link to support your answer, that a BIOS update will make the screen brighter?

Answer (score 0):

I did update the bios and installed the graphics driver. I tried to adjust the brightness in the graphics menu but it is affecting the picture quality. What I am looking for is a way to adjust the backlight beyond 100%, say about 120%. I also tried to modify the registry but it has no effect. Is there a command in cmd that can override the limit of backlight.